# Run void on activity done

Tags: android

Activity "MainActivity":

```
... (in some onClickListener)
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

Activity "NextActivity":

```
... (in onCreate)
finish();
...
```

After the line `finish();`, how can I run a method named `refreshContactList()` in `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` will be paused when `NextActivity` starts, and resumed when `NextActivity` ends.

So, if you override `onResume()` inside of `MainActivity`, it will be called when `NextActivity` finishes.

You will need to set some sort of flag or variable state so that you know which activity was active last (`onResume()` will also be called if the user leaves and comes back to the app).